# DISTINCT BY MAX()?

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I get the rows with the distinct `TypeID` with the maximum `EffectivityDate`?

#### Original Table

```
-----------------------------------------
| ID | TypeID | Value | EffectivityDate |
-----------------------------------------
|  1 |      1 |   2.3 |      1990-01-01 |
|  2 |      1 |   3.4 |      1999-10-31 |
|  3 |      2 |   1.1 |      1990-01-01 |
|  4 |      2 |   2.2 |      1999-10-31 |
|  5 |      3 |   6.1 |      1999-10-31 |
-----------------------------------------
```

#### Query Result

```
-----------------------------------------
| ID | TypeID | Value | EffectivityDate |
-----------------------------------------
|  2 |      1 |   3.4 |      1999-10-31 |
|  4 |      2 |   2.2 |      1999-10-31 |
|  5 |      3 |   6.1 |      1999-10-31 |
-----------------------------------------
```

Any help?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can get their maximum `EffectiveDate` in a subquery then join it again with its own table,

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    tableName a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT TypeID, MAX(EffectivityDate) maxDate
            FROM tableName
            GROUP BY TypeID
        ) b ON  a.TypeID = b.TypeID AND
                a.EffectivityDate = b.maxDate
```

## [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9ac97/1)

Comment: how are you typing so fast .. :)

Comment: +1 for quick reply. Side question Is there any tool to create Schema for table in SQLFiddle?

Comment: here's a simple way to do that, copy the table above, go back on SQLFiddle, click the `TEXT TO DDL` on the upper part then click `Append to DDL` btw, SQLFiddle is very amazing tool! :D

Comment: Oh God! I didn't ever see that tool. I was used to create Schema by typing manually :(. But thanks for suggesting that :)

Answer (score 6):

try this:

```
select * 
from   your_table t
join
       (select TypeID ,max(EffectivityDate ) as EffectivityDate 
        from your_table
        group by TypeID )a
on   t.TypeID =a.TypeID 
and  t.EffectivityDate =a.EffectivityDate
```

Comment: That should be `select t.*`